# Format Syncfusion Tooltip seperately from the axis

Tags: asp.net-core, tooltip, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I would like to be able to format the text in the tooltip differently than that y-axis. The y-axis does not show the cents. I would like to show the cents on the tool tip only. The formatting is done on the `<e-chart-primaryyaxis valueType=Double LabelFormat="$0" edgeLabelPlacement="Shift" title="Bill Amount"></e-chart-primaryyaxis>` adding ".00" to the format, changes the tooltip and the y-axis.

[Description Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG2OD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `textRender` event to format the tooltip according to your requirement.

Attaching a code snippet for your reference.

Code-snippet:

```
function tooltipRender(args) {

   args.text = args.data.pointY + '.00';

}
```